# Matlab 3D plot, 3rd value generated from simulink model

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I must generate a 3d plot for 3 variables .

- A, taking values from 0 to 15 (integer)
- B, taking values from 0 to 2 (floating point 0.1, 0.2)
- Z,  is the maximum value of a plot which is generated from the scope used in simulink model. i.e. max(plotnamegiven)

I should write a script in matlab by using a for loop for generating Z values in simulink for different values of A and B. I used the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
parfor a=0:15
for b=0:2
fprintf('Value of a: %d\n',a);
fprintf('Value of b: %d\n',b);
mil_offlinesim('Messungen.mat','C:\MasterThesis',5,3)
end
end
```

To generate the max value inside for loop I tried `like aa[a]= max(ans)`, but its not working.
Once I get the proper graph for Z, I should generate a 3d plot for A, B and Z

Please suggest a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call `mil_offlinesim('Messungen.mat','C:\MasterThesis',a,b)`